# XCode iOS8 Create EKCalendar from code with CalDAV credits

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calendar, caldav, ekeventstore

Is it possible to create an **EKCalendar** directly from code with **CalDAV credentials** (Server, User Name, Password...)?

Something like:

```
+ calendarForEntityType: withCalDAVCredentials: eventStore:
```

Or the only way it's to previous configure the CalDAV from Settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't create such programatically. But the Settings.app isn't the only way either, you might want to check out profiles.